# How to use Ubuntu One through terminal on mini-Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-one, command-line, 12.04

How do I access Ubuntu One through terminal?

I have only a minimal Ubuntu (precise), I downloaded all packages that I should be able to use, but how do I start?
How do I connect to the cloud using terminal only?

Answer (score 2):

Great article documenting this written [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RomanYepishev/UbuntuOne/ClientControl).

Answer (score 0):

12.04 user here. I realize this is a year late, but I'm posting this for everyone's benefit.

When I type into terminal `ubuntuone-installer`, Ubuntu One launches normally.

I tried this after typing `locate ubuntuone` and when a list came up I tried some of these commands;

```
python-ubuntuone-client
ubuntuone-client
ubuntuone-couch
ubuntuone-control-panel
ubuntuone-storage-protocol
gir1.2-ubuntuoneui-3.0.list
```

The only one that worked was `ubuntuone-installer`; don't let the name mislead you, because it is installed, the program will simply launch as normal.